# Delete Files and Folders inside Folder if is empty (Java)

Tags: java, file, directory

```
   String dirWay = "C:\\Project";
   int daysBack = 7;

    File directory = new File(dirWay);

 if(directory.exists()){
    File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

    long purgeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (daysBack * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    for(File listFile : listFiles) {

        if(listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) {      

            if(!listFile.delete()) {
                System.err.println("Unable to delete file: " + listFile);
               
            } else {

                System.out.println(listFile);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

This is working only for Project folder files. But i have some folders and files in the Project folder, and each folder has some folders and files.

How i can check inside all folder and check files last modified date and delete it if more than 7 days?

For example i have directory: C:/Project/JavaIdea/...
If files in the JavaIdea folder older than 7 days, i need delete all files and JavaIdea folder too.

Comment: It's a programming language; program it. You can write code that lists files of a directory, that asks for the last modified stamps, compares it to the current time, deletes them all in a loop, then deletes the dir they were in, and which uses recursion or a queue to apply the process recursively. There is no `.deleteFolderAndAllContentsIfAllContentsAreOlderThan(timestamp)` method and there never will be - but you can program that function!

Comment: .. and if you decide to do so, `java.io.File` is obsolete and should not be used. You want the classes in the`java.nio.file` package, primarily `Path`, `Paths`, and `Files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use `Files.walkFileTree`. `Files.walk` gives you a `Stream<Path>`, but folders come first, not after. The `FileVisitor` on the other hand uses two events for folders - before visiting, and after.

Something that could work (untested):

```
Deque<LongAdder> counts = new ArrayDeque<>(); // counting # of remaining files per level
Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(T dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        counts.push(new LongAdder());
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(T dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        long remaining = counts.pop().sum();
        if (remaining == 0) {
            // the directory is empty now, delete it
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(T file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (is old enough to delete) {
            // delete
        } else {
            counts.peek().increment();
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(T file, IOException exc) {
        counts.peek().increment();
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```